# EKParticipant in EventKit erroneously returns NO for isCurrentUser property

Tags: iphone, ios, eventkit

I'm attempting to determine which of an `EKEvent's` attendees (`EKPartipants`) is the current user. In iOS6, `EKParticipant` exposes a property called isCurrentUser

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKParticipantClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EKParticipant

which is supposed to provide precisely this information. Unfortunately, each time I lookup an `EKParticipant's` `isCurrentUser` property, it returns NO, even when that's clearly not the case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Updated findings:**

If you look up the event organizer, it correctly returns `isCurrentUser == YES` if you're the organizer. But, if you retrieve yourself from the set of attendees, it returns `isCurrentUser == NO`.

Example console output with the two different EKParticipant objects referring to the same person with the same email address:

```
(lldb) po [ekEvent.attendees objectAtIndex:3]
$20 = 0x208c1220 EKAttendee <0x208c1220> {UUID = CCD17C5E-FCB5-4BC9-8D9E-7E957B20025D;       
name= ----- -----; email = --------wa@me.com; status = 2; role = 0; type = 1}

(lldb) print [(EKParticipant *)[ekEvent.attendees objectAtIndex:3] isCurrentUser]
(BOOL) $15 = NO

(lldb) po ekEvent.organizer
$19 = 0x20b720e0 EKOrganizer <0x20b720e0> {UUID = FD0E434D-2C9F-4A6E-98DC-    
7FA6F27C3D1E; name = ----- -----; email = --------wa@me.com; isSelf = 1}

(lldb) print ekEvent.organizer.isCurrentUser
(BOOL) $16 = YES
```

Comment: Having the same problem here... Anything new? Any way to get the current identify from somewhere else?

Comment: does this only occur in ios6 or does this also happen in 7 and 8?

Answer (score 1):

Organiser of the event is not by default in the attendees list, you explicitly add him as attendees.

Organiser is considered different from attendees and is depicted with attribute organiser. If you use that object to access isCurrentUser it will provide you value Yes.

If you explicitly add the organiser email id as attendee it is considered different user, for that you need to compare attendees URL and check.

Example : User a..@a.com organised a meeting or event and invited b..@b.com
then in attendees you will have only b..@b.com and a..@a.com will be available as organiser.

In case you add a..@a.com as attendee also then its property isCurrentUser is No and you can check by comparing the attendees URL string itself with organiser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can determine which attendee of ekevent is the current user.

I found a way to make `isCurrentUser` work for any participant.
According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17222036/3683845 we can get attendee's email with `EKParticipant.URL.resourceSpecifier`

Well, you will get right email expect two guys. The one is the organizer, another is current user who uses the AppleID on this device.(If the event is an invitation)

When you access these two guys, their `resourceSpecifier` is something like

`/aMTA3MDAxMjE0MzEwNzAwMb6Y7GrNw2OCqzA8gkpxsctNZJxrzpebHm/principal/`

not the email format.

### **UPDATE**

It works for my iPhone on 9.3.2.

I can distinguish which one is current user in attendees.

When talk to event's organizer, if there is no invitee the organizer will be nil meaning this event is created by current user but `organizer.isCurrentUser` will be `NO`. Because `organizer` is `nil`.

When user invites some others to attend this event, `organizer` will be not nil and its `isCurrentUser` will be `YES`