# How to identify if an EKEvent has an EKParticipationStatus of pending (Not yet accepted)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, eventkit, ekevent

I have already tried the

```
if ([event participationStatus] == EKParticipantStatusPending)
```

and it is working. But the participationStatus of the EKEvent is not exposed and I'm afraid to use it as maybe it will result in a rejection because of a private API.

I have also tried looping through all of the event.attendees but it seems that the EKParticipant isCurrentUser does not give the correct value. It always returns NO

```
  for (EKParticipant* participant in event.attendees)

  {
    if ([participant isCurrentUser])

    {
      if (participant.participantStatus == EKParticipantStatusPending)

      {
        NSLog(@"NEEDS RESPONSE");
      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: `isCurrentUser` only works for `[event organizer]`. it will always return NO for participants other than the organizer, as you've observed.

Comment: is this the expected behavior?

Comment: it is the observed (undocumented) behavior. if you have access to the user's name or email (via other means), you can find the user among the attendees yourself and check status that way.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a tricky way to make `isCurrentUser` work for any participant.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17222036/3683845 we can get attendee's email with `EKParticipant.URL.resourceSpecifier`

Well, you will get right email expect two guys. The one is the organizer, another is current user who uses the AppleID on this device.

When you access these two guys, their `resourceSpecifier` is something like

`/aMTA3MDAxMjE0MzEwNzAwMb6Y7GrNw2OCqzA8gkpxsctNZJxrzpebHm/principal/`

not the email format.

Comment: i don't understand how you know if the participant is the current user.

Comment: @RaduVlad If you can not get the user's email which means this is current user or organizer.

Comment: I just used the `EKParticipant.URL.resourceSpecifier` method, and I got the email addresses. I used a tentative meeting from one of my google account to another. I never got something like `/aMTA3MDAxMjE0MzEwNzAwMb6Y7GrNw2OCqzA8gkpxsctNZJxrzpebHm/principal/`

Comment: @RaduVlad Are you sure your event is created by iCloud not sync from google calendar by iCloud?

Comment: It is probably synced.

Comment: :( perhaps that is the reason

Comment: but as you stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628493/ekparticipant-in-eventkit-erroneously-returns-no-for-iscurrentuser-property?rq=1 from IOS 9.3.2 the isCurrentUser property will return accordingly, so this works. thanks. Please update your answer for the others.