# Access email in EKParticipant/EKAttendee

Tags: ios, ekevent, ekeventkit

I want to get the email address of the attendee of an event in the EKEventKit.

I have the following code:

```
if ( event.attendees.count > 0)
{
    NSArray *people = event.attendees;
    for(EKParticipant *person in people)
    {
        if ( person.participantType == EKParticipantTypePerson && person.URL.resourceSpecifier.length > 0)
        {
            NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"event_id=%ld&name=%@&is_me=%d&email=%@&role=%@",event_id,person.name, person.isCurrentUser,person.URL.resourceSpecifier, @"attendee"];
            //<DO SOMETHING USEFUL WITH dataString>;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code person populates with the following data:

```
EKAttendee <0x17809acc0> {UUID = 4F657EA4-452A-412B-A9AA-FEC5551DC096; name = A. Real Person; email = realperson@therightdomain.com; status = 0; role = 0; type = 1}
```

**How to I access the email field?**

I tried (as above) to use URL.resourceSpecifier, but that frequently is some strange string that is definitely NOT an email address.

Answer (score 2):

The "Description" of the EKParticipant object is a property list of sorts.  I tried several different methods of parsing that list into something containing key:value pairs unsuccessfully.  So I wrote the following:

```
                            // This is re-useable code that converts any class description field into a dictionary that can be parsed for info
                    NSMutableDictionary *descriptionData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    for (NSString *pairString in [person.description componentsSeparatedByString:@";"])
                    {
                        NSArray *pair = [pairString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
                        if ( [pair count] != 2)
                            continue;
                        [descriptionData setObject:[[pair objectAtIndex:1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] forKey:[[pair objectAtIndex:0]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
                    }
```

With this I simply get the email address with

```
    [descriptionData valueForKey:@"email"]
```

Comment: It works as expected, i was facing an issue in iOS 12 and unable to get email field, your code worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer this same question in ["how to get ekevent EKparticipant email?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642786/how-to-get-ekevent-ekparticipant-email) thread:

What you need to do is use `EKPrincipal:ABRecordWithAddressBook` and then extract email from there. Like this:

```
NSString *email = nil;
ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
ABRecordRef record = [self.appleParticipant ABRecordWithAddressBook:book];
if (record) {
    ABMultiValueRef value = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    if (value
        && ABMultiValueGetCount(value) > 0) {
        email = (__bridge id)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(value, 0);
    }
}
```

Note that calling `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` is expensive so you might want to do that only once per session.

If you can't access the record, then fall back on `URL.resourceSpecifier`.

Comment: good answer,but when the participate is not in iPhone's addressbook,this record will be nil.

Comment: @frank Thanks. Yes, this is in general an unreliable API. I think we finally settled on sending `emailAddress` selector (undocumented) to `appleParticipant`.

Comment: @frank It shouldn't be dangerous (data loss, crashes, etc.) but it's definitely a dirty technique.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4:

```
private static func getParticipantDescriptionData(_ participant: EKParticipant) -> [String:String] {
  var descriptionData = [String: String]()
  for pairString in participant.description.components(separatedBy: ";") {
    let pair = pairString.components(separatedBy: "=")
    if pair.count != 2 {
      continue
    }
    descriptionData[pair[0].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)] =
      pair[1].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
  }
  return descriptionData
}
```