# Is there an API to get the email associated to an event on the macOS calendar?

Tags: swift, macos, calendar, eventkit

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the email account associated to calendar events on the Mac. Is there a way to do that?

I tried looking in to the `EKEvent` object and it does not indicate the email account. I also tried looking in to the `ACAccountStore`.

This is the swift code I used to retrieve the events:

```swift
func fetchCalendarEvents() {
    // Step 1: Create an instance of EKEventStore
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    // Step 2: Request access to the user's calendars
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { granted, error in
        if granted {
            // Step 3: Fetch the user's default calendar
            let defaultCalendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

            // Step 4: Create a predicate to fetch events from today onwards
            let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: Date(), end: Date().addingTimeInterval(365 * 24 * 60 * 60), calendars: [defaultCalendar!])

            // Step 5: Fetch the events using the predicate
            let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what I found is that IF there are attendees for an Event, I'm able to retrieve the email from the EKEvent.Organizer property. The Organizer is of type EKParticipant and there's a property EKParticipant.IsCurrentUser that indicates if the participant is the account owner. The rest of the attendees are listed in EKEvent.Attendees and if the Organizer is not the current user, one of the other attendees must be.

The only caveat to this approach is the event must have at least one attendee.

The code below works for Google, iCloud or Exchange accounts:

```swift
for ekEv in ekEvents {
    if let organizer = ekEv.organizer, organizer.isCurrentUser {
       let email = organizer.url?.resourceSpecifier 
    }
}
```

Comment: So this appears to assume that the organizer's `url` is a "mailto:" URL and getting that URL's `resourceSpecifier` effectively strips the `mailto:` portion of the URL leaving just the email address part. There are just so many cases where this solution is going to fail. But if it happens to work in your specific case, then I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: Thanks it's also verified by another user here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17222036/8624515